# Customize JSON with Jackson using Jersey

Tags: json, object, jersey, jackson, customization

I'm currently trying to retrieve info from this site: http://freegeoip.net/json/184.71.175.150, and read its contents into my own custom object using Jersey.

From this link https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.jackson, chapter 8.1.4, I wrote the following code:

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(IPInfo.class).register(JacksonFeature.class).build();

        Response response = client.target("http://freegeoip.net/json/184.71.175.150").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        IPInfo ip = response.readEntity(IPInfo.class);
```

Problem is, the code breaks at the response.readEntity line, the "HTTP Status 500 - Error reading entity from input stream" is shown on my servlet.

This is my object class:

```
public class IPInfo
{

private String _ip;
private String _countryCode;
private String _countryName;
private String _regionCode;
private String _regionName;
private String _city;
private String _zipCode;
private float _latitude;
private float _longitude;
private String _metroCode;
private String _areaCode;

public IPInfo(String ip,
              String countryCode,
              String countryName,
              String regionCode,
              String regionName,
              String city,
              String zipCode,
              float latitude,
              float longitude,
              String metroCode,
              String areaCode)
{
    _ip = ip;
    _countryCode = countryCode;
    _countryName = countryName;
    _regionCode = regionCode;
    _city = city;
    _zipCode = zipCode;
    _latitude = latitude;
    _longitude = longitude;
    _metroCode = metroCode;
    _areaCode = areaCode;
    _regionName = regionName;
}

public String getIp()
{
    return _ip;
}

public String getCountryCode()
{
    return _countryCode;
}

public String getCountryName()
{
    return _countryName;
}

public String getRegionCode()
{
    return _regionCode;
}

public String getCity()
{
    return _city;
}

public String getZipCode()
{
    return _zipCode;
}

public float getLatitude()
{
    return _latitude;
}

public float getLongitude()
{
    return _longitude;
}

public String getMetroCode()
{
    return _metroCode;
}

public String getAreaCode()
{
    return _areaCode;
}

public String getRegionName()
{
    return _regionName;
}

public void setIp(String ip)
{
    _ip = _ip;
}

public void setCountryCode(String countryCode)
{
    _countryCode = countryCode;
}

public void setCountryName(String countryName)
{
    _countryName = countryName;
}

public void setRegionCode(String regionCode)
{
    _regionCode = regionCode;
}

public void setRegionName(String regionName)
{
    _regionName = regionName;
}

public void setCity(String city)
{
    _city = city;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode)
{
    _zipCode = zipCode;
}

public void setLatitude(float latitude)
{
    _latitude = latitude;
}

public void setLongitude(float longitude)
{
    _longitude = longitude;
}

public void setMetroCode(String metroCode)
{
    _metroCode = metroCode;
}

public void setAreaCode(String areaCode)
{
    _areaCode = areaCode;
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to get the response as a String first.  Make sure that the response you are getting is in fact JSON and that it is formatted the same way as your object.

```
ClientResponse resp = service.path(PATH)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);

resp.getEntity(String.class)
```

Then you can test your deserialization code with an ObjectMapper
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue(resp.getEntity(String.class), CLASS)

Comment: You can chance the names of your fields with JSON annotations @JsonProperty("Name")

Answer (score 0):

I have  retrieved the info from the site: http://freegeoip.net/json/184.71.175.150, and read its contents in your custom object **IPInfo** using Jersey.

Here is my code to test the parse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Client client = Client.create();
  WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://freegeoip.net/json/184.71.175.150");
  ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                                         .get(ClientResponse.class);
  // Object to parser VO's
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  IPInfo ipInfo = objectMapper.readValue(response.getEntityInputStream(), IPInfo.class);
}
```

Note:

**Jersey 1.x way:**

```
Client client = Client.create(); 
WebResource webResource = client.resource(restURL).path("myresource/{param}"); 
String result = webResource.pathParam("param", "value").get(String.class);
```

**JAX-RS 2.0 way:**

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); 
WebTarget target = client.target(restURL).path("myresource/{param}"); 
String result = target.pathParam("param", "value").get(String.class);
```

And this is the IPInfo class (modified by adding the empty constructor, changing the "setIp" method and formatted. If you don't like the class formatted in this way I can undo it :P):

```
public class IPInfo {

    private String _ip;
    private String _countryCode;
    private String _countryName;
    private String _regionCode;
    private String _regionName;
    private String _city;
    private String _zipCode;
    private float _latitude;
    private float _longitude;
    private String _metroCode;
    private String _areaCode;

    public IPInfo() {

    }

    public IPInfo(String ip, String countryCode, String countryName,
            String regionCode, String regionName, String city, String zipCode,
            float latitude, float longitude, String metroCode, String areaCode) {
        _ip = ip;
        _countryCode = countryCode;
        _countryName = countryName;
        _regionCode = regionCode;
        _city = city;
        _zipCode = zipCode;
        _latitude = latitude;
        _longitude = longitude;
        _metroCode = metroCode;
        _areaCode = areaCode;
        _regionName = regionName;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return _ip;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return _countryCode;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return _countryName;
    }

    public String getRegionCode() {
        return _regionCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return _city;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return _zipCode;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return _latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return _longitude;
    }

    public String getMetroCode() {
        return _metroCode;
    }

    public String getAreaCode() {
        return _areaCode;
    }

    public String getRegionName() {
        return _regionName;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        _ip = ip;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        _countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        _countryName = countryName;
    }

    public void setRegionCode(String regionCode) {
        _regionCode = regionCode;
    }

    public void setRegionName(String regionName) {
        _regionName = regionName;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        _city = city;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        _zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        _latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        _longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setMetroCode(String metroCode) {
        _metroCode = metroCode;
    }

    public void setAreaCode(String areaCode) {
        _areaCode = areaCode;
    }

}
```

Note: You will need to add @JsonProperty("Name") as "pwilmot" says, in order to obtain the data with compound names with "_" as "region_code", or modify your class a little.

I didn't do it because I wanted to show you that with your class (without annotations) it was possible to parser and obtain the data from the URI into IPInfo